# Viewing JavaScript's message queue in a browser? (Event loop)

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is it possible to view a snapshot of JavaScript's message queue? How would I do so?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do this.  It's internal to the browser and not exposed via Javascript.

Comment: It may be viewable via a browser feature that we are both unware of.

Comment: You do understand that the only time there's something actually in the message queue is when the browser is otherwise busy doing something else and an event has occurred.  If the browser is not busy, then any event that occurs is immediately dispatched (and removed from the queue).  There's no such thing as an idle browser with things in the event queue.

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm looking for a snapshot feature as oppose to a real-time view. I'm pushing several messages onto the message queue within the same function, but the messages aren't being resolved as expected. Perhaps there's a browser that can take a snapshot whenever a message gets pushed.

Comment: What do you mean "pushing several messages onto the message queue"?  That isn't normally something you do directly so now I'm not sure you're talking about the same thing I am talking about.  Are you talking about Javascript's event queue?  Or something else?  How do you push these messages?

Comment: Something like `$('#element1').trigger('click');$('#element2').trigger('mouseenter');` should push multiple items onto the queue if appropriate event listeners exist.